# Replace CE Image with Assets resizing images in templates?

Tags: assets, ce-image

This is probably a newbie question but I checked the docs and am a little unclear.

I'm currently using CE Image to resize images in templates. I'm upgrading a site to use Assets for file management - I am wondering if Assets allows for the same type of image manipulation in tempts. That is can it:

- Resize images when they are called in the template?
- Cache the resized image for efficiency?
- Accept a max-width and max-height parameters and resize to scale?
- Accept a resize quality parameter for the quality?

If not, is there another solution for using Assets alone?

Bonus question: Can it do these things using S3 for storage?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assets does *none* of your four bullet points - these are all best done via CE Image as you're doing now (and it does all with aplomb). Why do you want to replace it? It's bar-none the best EE add-on for image manipulation (in the same way that Assets is the best file manager for EE).

Re: S3 - Assets *can* store your files in an S3 bucket, but if you're going to be resizing dynamically, then just store your master files locally and use [CE Image's S3 integration](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/installation#aws) instead.

Comment: Oh I'd just like to keep plugins to a minimum (an impossible task with EE2 *sigh*), and I could save another client some money by redeploying the CE licence to another new site.

Thanks for the info, looks like my development time will be pretty low :P

Thanks for the link to CE S3 integration. I was unfamiliar with that.